# How change checkbox value in code without clicking on UI elements?

Tags: r, shiny

I am looking for a method to change the value of the UI element in the code. Here is the case. There is checkbox "chk_filter_x" and data selector "si_parameter_x". By default, the checkbox is set to TRUE. So, when the form is loaded the data element is enabled.

By clicking on the checkbox or on the action button "Update" I can enable or disable the data element. This is workable. But I need to disable or enable data selector "si_parameter_x" by the value of "chk_filter_x" inside the code. It looks like generating click on UI. So, if "chk_filter_x" change value inside the code without external UI clicks - the data selector should react on it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_filter_x")),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_parameter_x"))

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  # 1. Filter 'X'
  output$uo_filter_x <- renderUI({
    checkboxInput("chk_filter_x", "Filter X", value = TRUE)
  })
  
  # 2. Values 'X'
  output$uo_parameter_x <- renderUI({

   # PROBLEM:
   #
   # How to set 'input$chk_filter_x' value to FALSE here that will change enable / disable status of 'si_parameter_x'
   #

    tags$table(
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(selectizeInput("si_parameter_x", "Value X", choices = c("x1", "x2"), selected = "x1", multiple=TRUE)),
        tags$td(actionButton("btn_update", "Update"))
      )
    )
  })
  
  # 3. Update checkbox
  observeEvent(input$btn_update, {
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "chk_filter_x", value = !input$chk_filter_x)
  })
  
  # 4. Observe event
  observeEvent(input$chk_filter_x, {
    if(input$chk_filter_x) {
      shinyjs::enable("si_parameter_x")
    } else {
      shinyjs::disable("si_parameter_x")
    }
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: How exactly is `chk_filter_x` changing value inside the code?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `observeEvent` which reacts to UI input of `input$chk_filter_x` you can use `observe`.

```
observe({
    if(!is.null(input$chk_filter_x) && input$chk_filter_x) {
      shinyjs::enable("si_parameter_x")
    } else {
      shinyjs::disable("si_parameter_x")
    }
  })
```

Complete app code -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_filter_x")),
  fluidRow(uiOutput("uo_parameter_x"))
  
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  # 1. Filter 'X'
  output$uo_filter_x <- renderUI({
    checkboxInput("chk_filter_x", "Filter X", value = TRUE)
  })
  
  # 2. Values 'X'
  output$uo_parameter_x <- renderUI({
    
    tags$table(
      tags$tr(
        tags$td(selectizeInput("si_parameter_x", "Value X", choices = c("x1", "x2"), selected = "x1", multiple=TRUE)),
        tags$td(actionButton("btn_update", "Update"))
      )
    )
  })
  
  # 3. Update checkbox
  observeEvent(input$btn_update, {
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "chk_filter_x", value = !input$chk_filter_x)
  })
  
  
  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$chk_filter_x) && input$chk_filter_x) {
      shinyjs::enable("si_parameter_x")
    } else {
      shinyjs::disable("si_parameter_x")
    }
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```